# Syntax error when using aggregation in update query

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 tables.(Invoice,Installments).
First one is basic details of an invoice.

```
Invoice table:
---------
Invoice_Num
Value
Down_Payment
Balance
Customer_name
Item_ID
Last_Paid_date
```

and etc.

Second is installments of the invoice.

```
Installment table:
---------
Invoice_Num
Date
Paid
Balance
```

ex : Some one bought a laptop on 2015-June-25. Total price 1000$ . He paid 200 $ as down payment. Balance was 800 $ . Then he paid 5 installment like this

```
Date           Paid   Balance
2015-July-25   100$   700$
2015-Aug-25    100$   600$
2015-Sep-10    150$   450$
2015-Oct-18    100$   350$
2015-Nov-23    120$   230$
```

Now I want to update 2015-Nov-23 in first table column name "Last_Paid_date"

I tried this.

```
update invoice,installment 
set invoice.last_paid_date=max(date) 
where invoice.invoice_num=installment.invoice_num 
group by installment.num
```

There was Syntax error:

> java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'group by installment.card' at line 1

Comment: what does the actual syntax error look like that you are getting from mysql server? can you post?

Comment: Yes sir. here is it. 
`java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by installment.card' at line 1`

Comment: Then what will the right code sir.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use group by in an update statement. What you should do here is write a query to get the max date in each group, and use a `JOIN` in the update to set the right values:

```
UPDATE invoice i
JOIN(
   SELECT invoice_num, MAX(datecolumn) AS latestDate
   FROM installment
   GROUP BY invoice_num) tmp ON tmp.invoice_num = i.invoice_num
SET i.last_paid_date = tmp.latestDate;
```

Comment: This is untested, as I don't have any sample data to create an SQL Fiddle with. If you are unable to get this to work, let me know.

Comment: Even if it is untested, you pointed out the error in his update statement and provided him with enough of an answer to move forward...+1

Comment: I was about to post the same answer but wasted some time making a fiddle instead... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d17d46/1 tested and works as expected.

Comment: @jpw thanks for adding. I decided to answer before making the Fiddle haha. Here's mine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bcd8/1

Comment: @McAdam331 Fastest wins! In any case the question is a duplicate of several other.

Comment: @jpw do you think I should delete this answer, or leave the question as a pointer to the others?

Comment: @McAdam331 Nah, don't bother. Keep the rep. The question will be closed anyway. It's not bad to have duplicates anyway - makes them easier to find.

Comment: @jpw  Thank you sir for payed your attention on me.

Comment: Without dupes we wouldn't have 331k mysql questions

Comment: @HasanDulanga glad we could help. Just be aware of it and try a little more research before asking next time. If this answer helped you feel free to upvote and accept it.

Comment: @McAdam331 I researched sir. The didn't help for me. As I do not know English well ,I couldn't match nice key words for the searching. Any way I took your advise for me.  I accepted the answer.And thank you very much sir.